# Get last Item from LookUpSet in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services

How can I get the last item of a array returned by LookupSet?

For instance, I can get the first, second or sixt item with (0), (1), (5).

```
LookupSet(source_expression, destination_expression, result_expression, dataset)(5)
```

Is there a way to return the last item instead of a specific position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the array for a LOOKUPSET but I think you could use you use LENGTH on another LOOKUPSET for it:

```
=LOOKUPSET(<source_expression>, <destination_expression>, <result_expression>, 'dataset1')(LOOKUPSET(<source_expression>, <destination_expression>, <result_expression>, 'dataset1').Length - 1)
```

**Length** will return the number of rows returned for the LOOKUPSET. I think you'll need to subtract 1 since the array starts at 0 and not 1.